# Start new process as Network Service throws "The user name or password is incorrect"

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to start a child process under the Network Service account and I just can't get the right combination of username/password. Code:

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Test2.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args[0];
proc.StartInfo.Domain = "NT AUTHORITY";
proc.StartInfo.UserName = "NETWORK SERVICE";
proc.StartInfo.Password = new SecureString();
proc.Start();
```

Comment: you can maybe run as an administrator with proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search revealed [this page](http://geek.hubkey.com/2008/02/impersonating-built-in-service-account.html). It appears you will need to rely on the win32 api, specifically these methods:

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(string username, string domain,
                                          string password, LogonType logonType,
                                          LogonProvider logonProvider,
                                          out IntPtr userToken);


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr userToken);
```

I'm guessing the reason it's not so simple to do this in .Net is because it is a very odd requirement, as this user should be used by Windows Services, and that is not the concern of the executing code.